# iphone deployment version requirements

Tags: iphone, xcode

Is there a specific version that the deployment requirements need to be set to in xcode to submit an app to the app store?  I keep getting a "not accepting this SDK" error when I try to upload the binary but my target deployment OSs are all recent (3.0, 4.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your Base SDK is 4.0.  Deployment Target can be whatever minimum OS your app requires.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed an official release of the SDK. Apple does not accept submissions from pre-release SDK's unless expressly stated (e.g. 4.0 GM)

Comment: How do I confirm that I have an official release of the SDK?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action#downloads As of today, Xcode 3.2.3 (1688), Posted on June 21, 2010